# Make in input value as in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

How can i make in input value as in array

```
var obj = {};
var data = $('#provilege').val();
var obj = eval(data);

//var obj = {"test_1":"1","test_2":"1","test_3":"0","test_4":"0","test_5":"0","test_6":"1","test_7":"0"}

$.each( obj, function( key, value ) { 
    alert("key " + key + " has value " + obj[key]);
  if(value == 0){
        $('#'+ key).addClass('hidden');// hidden only the obj has value = 0
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8TT4p/1672/

Thanks for your help;

Comment: Use `JSON.parse` and not `eval` for parsing JSON.

Comment: Your `obj` value is an object, not an array.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean with " make in input value as in array"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `JSON.parse()` for parsing JSON.

Correct format of value should be like this, where i have used `"` instead of `'`, otherwise you will get error while parsing **JSON**:

```
{"test_1":"1","test_2":"1","test_3":"0","test_4":"0","test_5":"0","test_6":"1","test_7":"0"}
```

[**Updated demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8TT4p/1675/)

Answer (score 0):

First, use `JSON.parse()` to parse your object string to Object. To achieve this, you will have to replace all occurrences of `'` to `"`.

Second, fetch all keys using `Object.keys(objectName);` This will return an array of all keys.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8TT4p/1676/)

Following code depicts the same:

```js
var obj = {};
var _data = $('#provilege').val();

// Replace single quotes to double quotes and then parse.
var processedObj = JSON.parse(_data.replace(/\'/g, '\"'));

// Fetch keys from processed object
var _keys = Object.keys(processedObj);

_keys.forEach(function(item) {
  $("#" + item).text(processedObj[item]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="test_1">test_1</p>
<p id="test_2">test_2</p>
<p id="test_3">test_3</p>
<p id="test_4">test_4</p>
<p id="test_5">test_5</p>
<p id="test_6">test_6</p>
<p id="test_7">test_7</p>
<p id="test_8">test_8</p>
<p id="test_9">test_9</p>

<p id="test"></p>

<input type="hidden" id="provilege" value="{'test_1':'1','test_2':'1','test_3':'0','test_4':'0','test_5':'0','test_6':'1','test_7':'0'}" />
```